# Java: How to read a specific line from a text file?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have this text file:

```
2013001  Jaymarion Manalo L. Service Crew March 15, 2013   8:00   12:00   13:00   17:00   10.0
2013001  Jaymarion Manalo L. Service Crew March 16, 2013   8:00   12:05   13:05   17:30   10.0
```

Now, I have a condition that if String date1 = "March 15, 2013", it will read the line where it belongs and will only get the "8:00", "12:00", "13:00", and "17:00" and display it on the text fields I have declared. I mean, is that even possible? How is it done? I hope you're getting what I'm trying to say. I am so new at Java -_-

Comment: If the condition is based on line contents, all you can do is read the file sequentially, line by line, until you get to the right one.

Comment: You can iterate over all lines, check `if(line.contains("March 15, 2013"){` and print it or do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read file as a list of strings using [`FileUtils.readLines()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29)
This will give you a list of Strings. Then iterate over the list and look for the date using `string.contains("March 15, 2013")`.

Note: *I can share the complete code with you, but you should try to code with the above information.*

Answer (score 1):

Ofcource this possible.

You need to read the file line by line. Check each line if it contains `date1`. If it does then extract and parse the data you want.

Here is a sample code how you can achieve this with standard api:

```
public class ReadFileLineByLineAnExtractSomeText {

    private static final String src = "test.txt";
    private static final String date1 = "March 15, 2013";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void genTextFile() throws IOException {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(src);
        os.write(("blah bla foo bar\n" +
                "2013001  Jaymarion Manalo L. Service Crew March 15, 2013   8:00   12:00   13:00   17:00   10.0\r\n" + 
                "2013001  Jaymarion Manalo L. Service Crew March 16, 2013   8:00   12:05   13:05   17:30   10.0\r" +
                "... the end").getBytes());
        os.close();
    }


    @Test
    public void testReadAndExtract() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(src));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while(line != null) {
            lineNumber++;
            int i = line.indexOf(date1);
            if(i != -1) {
                int s = i + date1.length();
                int e = line.length();
                System.out.println(date1 + " found in line " + lineNumber  + " at index " + i + ", extract text from " + s + " to " + e);
                String extractedText = line.substring(s, e);
                String[] extractedTextParts = extractedText.trim().split("\\s+");
                for(String part : extractedTextParts) {
                    if(isTime(part)) {
                        System.out.println("    '" + part + "'");   
                    }
                }
            }
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
    }

    private boolean isTime(String part) {
        return part == null ? false : part.matches("\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}");
    }
}
```

Output

```
March 15, 2013 found in line 2 at index 42, extract text from 56 to 94
    '8:00'
    '12:00'
    '13:00'
    '17:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can iterate to the line which you want and then you can try something like this:-

```
String s= FileUtils.readLines(filename).get(lineNumber);
```

For more information on `FileUtils.readLines()` check [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29) out.

Answer (score 0):

to read line from line...

```
try {
    FileReader fileReader = 
        new FileReader(fileName);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
        new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    //in any loop use bufferedreader.readline() untill you get your desired line
    //to part your string use split()
    bufferedReader.close();         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileReaderService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReaderService fileReaderService = new FileReaderService();
        fileReaderService.performExecute("March 15, 2013");
    }

    public void performExecute(String inputPattern) {
        List<String[]> matches = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Guest/Desktop/your-file.txt"); /*change your file path here*/
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (strLine.contains(inputPattern)) {
                    String[] splits = strLine.split("[\\s]{3,}"); /*splits matching line with 3 consecutive white spaces*/
                    matches.add(splits);
                }
            }
            dataInputStream.close();

            for (String[] items : matches) {
                System.out.println(items[1] + "\t" + items[2] + "\t" + items[3] + "\t" + items[4]);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
8:00    12:00   13:00   17:00
```